# Proof that $\int_X K(\cdot,y)f(y) \, d\mu(y)$ is measurable if $K, f\in L^2$?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $(X,\mathscr A,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $K\in L^2(X^2,\mathscr A \otimes \mathscr A,\mu\otimes\mu),$ and $f\in L^2(X,\mathscr A,\mu).$

I am trying to prove that $F(x)=\int_X K(x,y)f(y) \, d\mu(y)$ is $\mathscr A$-measurable. The book I am reading claims it is, without proof.*

Here is my current progress:

If we can show that $\int_{X^2}|K(x,y)|\,|f(y)|\,d(\mu\otimes\mu)<\infty,$ then Fubini's theorem immediately guarantees that $F$ is measurable. Using Fubini's theorem on $K$ gives $|K(x,\cdot)|^2\in L^1$ a.e., which is equivalent to $K(x,\cdot)\in L^2$ a.e. So Cauchy-Schwartz gives:

$$\int_X |K(x,y)| |f(y)|\, d\mu(y)\leq \| K(x,\cdot)\|_2 \|f\|_2\qquad \text{a.e.}$$

In the comments, Kavi Rama Murthy suggests squaring both sides of this inequality and integrating in $x$. This gives

$$\int_X\left(\int_X |K(x,y)| |f(y)|\, d\mu(y)\right)^2 d\mu(x)\leq \| K(x,\cdot)\|_2^2 \|f\|_2^2.$$

So perhaps the left side here simplifies to the expression $\int_{X^2}|K||f|d(\mu\otimes\mu)?$

---

*V. Moretti, *Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics*. Example 4.16 (4).

Comment: This is part of the standard proof of Fubini's Theorem That is why they don''t give any proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But Fubini's theorem (and its proof) requires that $K(x,y)f(y)$ be non-negative, or that $\int_{X\times Y}K(x,y)f(y)d\mu(x)\otimes d\mu(y)<\infty.$ I don't see how either of those follows.

Comment: The second condition holds by Holder's inequality. You can also split $K$ and $f$ into positive and negative parts for an alternative proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But $K$ and $f$ are in different $L^2$ spaces, so I don't see how Holder's inequality applies. Maybe it does after viewing $f$ as a function on $X^2$, but that would require $\int_{X\times X} |f(x, y)|^2\,d(\mu\otimes\mu)<\infty,$ which does not seem obvious to me.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $F(x)$ is finite?

Comment: Square both sides of your inequality and intergate w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Am I missing some way to convert $\int_X (\int_X |K(x,y)| |f(y)| d\mu(y))^2 d\mu(x)$ into $\int_{X^2}|K(x,y)| |f(y)| d(\mu\otimes\mu)$?

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of Fubini's theorem include the following. Let $(X,\mathcal{F}_X,\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{F}_Y,\nu)$ are $\sigma-$finite. If $g:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{F}_X\times\mathcal{F}_Y-$measurable and $g \in L^1(\mu\times\nu)$, then
$$x\to \int_{Y}g(x,y)d\nu(y) $$
is not just $\mathcal{F}_X-$measurable, but is also a function in $L^1(\mu)$. In your example you have $g(x,y)=K(x,y)f(y)$.

I actually don't think that $g$ will necessarily be integrable with respect to the product measure, but I think we can get the result using $\sigma-$finiteness. Let $\{A_n\}$ be an increasing sequence of sets of finite measure which expand to $X$. Then consider the functions $g_n(x,y)=1_{A_n}(x)K(x,y)f(y)$ and call $F_n(x)=\int_X 1_{A_n}(x)K(x,y)f(y)d\mu(y)=F(x)1_{A_n}(x)$. Then for any $n$ we have that
\begin{align*}\int_X\int_X |g_n(x,y)|d\mu(y)d\mu(x) &=\int_X\int_X |1_{A_n}(x)K(x,y)f(y)|d\mu(y)d\mu(x)\\
&= \int_{A_n}\int_X |K(x,y)f(y)|d\mu(y)d\mu(x)\\
&\leq \int_{A_n}||K(x,\cdot)||_2 ||f||_2 d\mu(x)\\
&= ||f||_2\int_{A_n}||K(x,\cdot)||_2 d\mu(x)
\end{align*}
Now the function $x\to ||K(x,\cdot)||_2^2$ is measurable by Fubini's Theorem and the assumption that $K\in L^2(X^2)$. Since $z\to\sqrt{z}$ is a Borel function, the composition $x\to \sqrt{||K(x,\cdot)||_2^2}=||K(x,\cdot)||_2$ is measurable. Hence the set $B=\{x: ||K(x,\cdot)||_2\leq 1\}$ is measurable. Hence
\begin{align*}
\int_{A_n}||K(x,\cdot)||_2 d\mu(x) &= \int_{A_n\cap B}||K(x,\cdot)||_2 d\mu(x) + \int_{A_n\cap B^c}||K(x,\cdot)||_2 d\mu(x)\\
&\leq  \int_{A_n\cap B}1 d\mu(x) + \int_{A_n\cap B^c}||K(x,\cdot)||_2^2 d\mu(x)\\
&= \mu(A_n\cap B) + \int_{A_n\cap B^c}\int_X |K(x,y)|^2 d\mu(y)d\mu(x)\\
&\leq \mu(A_n\cap B) +||K||_2
\end{align*}
Now both terms on the right are finite since $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ and $K\in L^2$ by assumption. This then shows that $\int_X\int_X |g_n(x,y)|d\mu(y)d\mu(x) < \infty$ and by Fubini's Theorem we may conclude that $F_n(x)=F(x)1_{A_n}(x)$ is a measurable function. Well $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ almost everywhere, so $F$ is the pointwise limit a.e. of measurable functions, hence $F$ is a measurable function. Do note that $F$ may not be integrable.

Comment: I am assuming $\sigma$-finiteness (updated the post about this), but not much else.

Comment: @WillG I updated my answer, let me know if it looks good

Comment: Thanks for this nice rigorous proof. I am not sure how you get $\int_{A\cap B^c} \|K(x,\cdot)\|_2^2d\mu(x)=\int_{A_n}\int_X |K(x,y)|^2d\mu(y)d\mu(x).$ Should this step have a $\leq$ instead?

Comment: Also toward the end you say $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ almost everywhere. But this is even "everywhere," no?

Comment: @WillG I think it should be true, but because we are working with measurable functions, I tend to always tack on the almost everywhere requirement to be safe. For the integral, I am just using that $||K(x,\cdot)||_2^2 = \int_X |K(x,y)|^2 d\mu(y)$, but I edited by answer to make sure I didn't change the $A\cap B^c$ to the set $A$

Comment: Got it. Well I think this all works out then. I'm still curious if there is some "easy" answer that can be found by simple manipulations, as suggested in the comments. I'll keep this open for a few days to see if anyone has insight on this, and then accept this answer.